# factory.function is not a function in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I want to delete the items in cart. For that i use function canceldummy() for the single item. Here my problem is, while deleting i got an error...

```
NewOrderFactory.deleteDummyOrder is not a function
at deleteDummy (TiffinServices.js:55)
at Scope.$scope.canceldummy (TiffinControllers.js:357)
at fn (eval at <anonymous> (angular.js:13365), <anonymous>:4:651)
at callback (angular.js:23613)
at Scope.$eval (angular.js:16052)
at Scope.$apply (angular.js:16152)
at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:23618)
at HTMLAnchorElement.n.event.dispatch (jquery-2.2.0.min.js:3)
at HTMLAnchorElement.r.handle (jquery-2.2.0.min.js:3)
```

html code:

```
<a href="" title="Remove item" class="button remove-item" ng-click="canceldummy($index)"><span><span>Remove item</span></span></a>
```

This is my Controller code.

```
mainCtrl.controller("OrderController",function($scope,NewOrderService){
    $scope.canceldummy=function(idx){
        NewOrderService.deleteDummy(idx);
    }
})
```

This is my Services code

```
servctrl.service("NewOrderService",function(NewOrderFactory){                                                 
    this.deleteDummy=function(idx){ 
        NewOrderFactory.deleteDummyOrder(idx);
    }
})
```

This is my Factorys code

```
factmodule.factory("NewOrderFactory",function(){
    var OrderItemList={Items:[]}
    return{
        deleteDummyOrder: function(idx){
            OrderItemList.Items.splice(idx,1);
        }
    }
})
```

How to remove this error?

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is in the factory, try this code in your factory :

```
factmodule.factory("NewOrderFactory",function(){

  var OrderItemList={Items:[]};
  OrderItemList.deleteDummyOrder: function(idx){
      OrderItemList.Items.splice(idx,1);      
  }
  return OrderItemList;
})
```